# Why can't Excel "filter by color" on styles created by openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I created an Excel workbook and worksheet using `openpyxl`.

I set the fill and font colour of some cells like this:

```
ws.cell(row=2, column=1).font = some_font_defined_earlier
ws.cell(row=2, column=1).fill = some_fill_defined_earlier
```

The font and fill are applied correctly and look great in Excel.
However, in the autofilter of row 1, I do not see the usual "Filter by Color" options that I typically see with coloured cells when they've been coloured in Excel.

Have I applied the styles in a wrong/different way?
How can I set the fill and font colour but also have Excel allow me to filter on the colours?

**EDIT1:**

To be clear, I have applied the autofilter using:

```
ws.auto_filter.ref = ws.dimensions
```

I see the autofilter on the values, but not the colours. `Filter by Color` is greyed out, even though many of the cells have colours.

Comment: Do you want something like this: [`[python][openpyxl] Filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Bopenpyxl%5D+Filter)

Comment: Thanks @stovfl. After browsing those questions, I see only questions relating to applying the filter, not to my specific problem of `Filter by Color` being missing.

Comment: ***"when they've been coloured in Excel."***: Go the reverse way, do coloured by *Excel* and see how `openpyxl` sees the probably assigned `.auto_filter`. Read the docu note: [Using filters and sorts](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html?highlight=auto_filter)

Answer (score 0):

It appears the answer to this is all in Excel, not in the Workbook. Excel seems to have some unpredictable behaviour with respect to `Filter by Color` being greyed out.

In my case, I had more than 10,000 rows and, as described in #4 of [Tips & Tricks 120 - Filter by Color Drop Down Menu Greyed Out Problem](http://eforexcel.com/wp/tips-tricks-120-filter-by-color-drop-down-menu-greyed-out-problem/), `Filter by Color` can just not work:

> 4. Also if first colored cell appears after approximately 10000 rows, Excel may not detect the color. To overcome this behavior, put a color
>      in the first cell and now it will enable the Filter by Color. Only
>      thing is that this colored cell will be extra in your filtered list.